# When I search for any city in google earth it zooms in at a wrong location

Tags: locale, google-earth

this is very weird.
I open google earth and search for "athens, greece" for example, and even though it will through a pin on top of the correct location, the google earth globe will turn and zoom in towards a location in the sahara desert!

Could this be related to the regional settings on the computer?

```
nass@stardust:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=el_GR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

What else could it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can verify that by changing the regional settings to en_US.UTF-8 the problem vanishes. The obvious difference is that greek uses 'comma' as a decimal separator and that mixes google earth somehow.

I am not sure if this is a bug on google-earth's code (since this error does not show up in,say, windows OS) or in ubuntu. But they should probably be notified.

Answer (score 6):

With `google-earth-pro-stable-7.3.2.5776-0.x86_64`, I use `LC_NUMERIC=C` to fix the problem while keeping the language of the application unchanged.
You can run:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C google-earth-pro
```

or edit `/opt/google/earth/pro/googleearth` to add this just after the header of file :

```
export LC_NUMERIC=C
```

Comment: This is the less invasive solution and keeps your locale as it should be according to (guess what) your localisation! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/googleearth-package/+bug/1160289

These are the instructions I followed:

"I created a script and named it "earth.sh" (without the quotes).

```
  sudo gedit earth.sh
```

and placed the following lines inside it:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 LANG=en_US google-earth
```

Then I placed said script inside /opt/google/earth/free:

```
 sudo cp earth.sh /opt/google/earth/free
```

Then I opened /usr/share/applications/google-earth.desktop:

```
 sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-earth.desktop
```

and changed the "exec" command to "/opt/google/earth/free/earth.sh".

Now google earth opens and the search function works ok even if the language is not US english."

Definitively its an issue with the regional settings.

Comment: Thank you! This got me on the right track. But instead of your exact steps, I just edited /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth (a shell script) and inserted LANG=en_US right after the interpreter line. One change and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Between the last line starting with a `#` and FindPath(), insert `LANG=en_US` and save

it works just fine on my Lubuntu 18.04 / Google Earth Pro 7.3.1.4507 (64-bit) with Swedish locale. There are no problems with non-english letters (Å, Ä, Ö)

So that part of the file now looks like this:

```
# Function to find the real directory a program resides in.
LANG=en_US
FindPath()
```