# Is there a way to edit/tweak the regional settings?

Tags: locale, editing, tweak

Is there a way to tweak the regional settings and , while preserving greek locale, I can change the decimal separator to en_US? as this is necessary for google earth to work [correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338797/when-i-search-for-any-city-in-google-earth-ubuntu-12-04-ti-zooms-in-at-a-wrong-l)?

- I don't see any button to change the number format in the Language Support dialog.

Answer (score 1):

To change a single locale category, you can edit your `~/.profile` file. Try adding this line to `~/.profile`:

`export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: I am looking for more fine grain control than choosing various locales at the level of LC_<sections>. namely to modify a locale.

Comment: @nass: I see that you chose to modify the locale specification itself, which indeed gives you complete control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go to System Setting and select Language Support. There you'll find two menus: Language and Regional Formats; change the number format in the latter.

Comment: I don't see any button to change the number format...